# After booting windows 10 from usb getting bsod: KERNEL SECURITY CHECK FAILURE

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod

Some context:
My windows 10 started giving me random bsods like CRITICAL STRUCTURE CORRUPTION, PAGE FAULT IN NON PAGED AREA and MEMORY MANAGEMENT while surfing and sometimes on startup. It happened when i closed the lid while browsing on google chrome and forced shutdown on laptop.

I also was carrying my laptop, so maybe hard went wrong.

I tried to do sfc/checknow but got message that something left corrupt.

I reinserted RAM, everything went OK after that but then I got bsod again, so I decided to do fresh start and got error, which tells that there is error in the disk

So I decided to do install from image file, and chose restore point from a week ago.

I was warned, that if something went wrong, my OS will break, but I still did it. My OS got broke. It said, that i need to boot from new media like usb, and at this point I'm stuck.

OS starts, I see blue window logo, in the second it starts loading - I get bsod KERNET SECURITY CHECK FAILURE, laptop restarts and loop repeats

Tied to change lots of random options in bios and nothing changes

I use KMSpico windows 10 without burning it into usb

I should mention, that my laptop is 7 years old and i have already changed power jack for 2 times.

Comment: "but got message that something left corrupt." - Please provide us with the necessary information, within the body of your question, in order to answer your question.  Please

Comment: I can't remember it well, but when i checked error log I caught that there is error because of dublicate fonts in Microsoft folder, also there was a mesaage, that winload.exe is missing to be able to boot. I didn't think that I won't be able to figure it out easy thus I didn't even bother to read whole log 

Comment: Do you know how to get BSOD information from kernel memory dump?

Comment: I can't even get into safe mode, OS surely broke, I don't know other way to get memory dump but via navigating in OS

Comment: He might not have a memory dump.  If you can get into the BIOS there may be diagnostics you can run to test the hard drive. If there are no diagnostics, then take the hard drive out and attach it to another machine, then run diagnostics on it from there.  A 7 year old machine....Start thinking about replacing the hard drive if you plan to keep on using it.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured:
The solution was to install windows 7 and then windows 10.
So, I analyzed it like this:
1. Tried to install windows 10 2016 from kms.
2. Tried to install windows 10 2018 via media creation tool. 
3. Tried to install windows 10 2017 from friends flash
4. Install windows 7 2014 from another friends flash.
(ran sfc/scan now and chkdsk /f without errors)
5. Reinstall windows 10 from kms.(still getting bugs on pin, but idc)

Also I bought new hdd, but when i replaced it I was still getting the same errors (bsod CACHE MANAGEMENT, bsod KERNEL SECURITY FAILURE, pop up corrrupt or missing file, pop up can't find file)

EDIT:
Windows 10 froze the next day and same bsods after installation shown up. My guess it is because of my old i-3-22000 proccesor thus I'm currently using win 7